# Как с помощью JS изменить CSS div блокам с одинаковым названием?

Tags: javascript, html, css, блок

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>задача 3</title>
<style>body {
    background-color: bisque;
}
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
} </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="one"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="two"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="three"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="two"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="one"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="two"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="three"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="one"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="two"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="three"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <button class="btn" onclick="start()">Нажми</button>
    <script>
function start() {
   document.getElementsByClassName('two').style.border = "7px double black";
    
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Надо что бы по кнопке добавилась рамка только тем div блокам с именем класса two. Рамка должна быть двойная чёрная.

Comment: Что именно возвращает метод `getElementsByClassName`, знаете?

Comment: Нет, но он должен брать все значения с элемента. А уже потом из него я хочу изменять style у всех элементов с названием  класса two

Comment: function start() {
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName('two');
    style = div[0].style;
    style.border = '7px double black'

Comment: А как вы используете что-то, если не знаете что он делает? Это как?

Comment: *"он должен брать все значения с элемента."* --- вы лучше почитайте документацию, а не придумывайте свои определения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const btnsTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.two');
btnsTwo.forEach(item => item.classList.add('bordered'))
```

и стилизуете .bordered как хотите - хоть двойную линию, хоть тройную

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять более развернутые ответы

Comment: @SwaD, это стоило автору вопроса писать, а не ответа ;)